# Custom Shipping Dropdown Box In Opencart 1.5

Tags: php, mysql, opencart

I have been trying to add a drop down box of my own Shipping Methods that I will handle on my own later after the order is placed. I have modified the flat rate php to create this. I am querying a table of custom shipping methods for each store. Does anybody know of an extension that can do this for me? I have searched and can't find it or does anybody have an idea how to do this? I do not need calculations of anything for the ship methods. The user just selects a ship method from a dropdown and places the order. I handle that manually after the order is placed.

When I try to continue on to placing the order, I get a warning: Warning: Shipping method required!

I cannot find what I need to change or modify to allow me to pass me through this step. I think it has to do that everything for shipping is done with radio buttons and can't handle the dropdown. Can anybody please shed any light or have any ideas to solve this issue?

Comment: you mean need to create a custom shipping method, like create new shipping module, its Free shipping or paid.?

Answer (score 0):

The reason it is giving you that response is because, the website is built to handle Shipping Costs, From a customers perspective do you really think that they will continue to pay for an item when they dont know clearly how much the shipping is costing them? Anyway there is a plugin for playing with the shipping methods would probably be on http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension&path=4 But you should seriously consider setting up proper amounts for each country or region.